# Google Chrome - Prevent form resubmission on refresh in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails3, and I'm building very simple app (in which I don't want AJAX). Anyway, I have the `index` and `create` actions. The `index` action contains form:

```
<%= form_for @message, url: promote_index_path do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

My `promote_controller` looks like this:

```
  def index
    @message = Message.new url: @last_video, message_body: @last_message
  end

  def create
    @message = current_user.messages.new(params[:message])
    @message.get_video_id
    if @message.save
      redirect_to promote_index_url, flash: {notice: "Promotion has been started"}
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  end
```

This all works fine, except for when form is submitted successfully, and notice is flashed, if user hits `F5`, the form resubmits itself. Which should not be the case, since I am doing `redirect_to` after successful save. I believe I am doing something fundamentally wrong here, so please help me out.

EDIT:
Here is my `routes.rb`

```
 resources :home
  resources :find
  resources :promote
  resources :settings
  root to: 'home#index'
  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  match 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
  match 'find', to: 'find#index', as: 'find'
  match 'promote', to: 'promote#index', as: 'promote'
  match 'settings', to: 'settings#index', as: 'settings'
```

And here is my `rake routes`

```
Jans-MacBook-Pro-2:tp3 jan$ rake routes
settings_index GET    /settings/index(.:format)          settings#index
    home_index GET    /home(.:format)                    home#index
               POST   /home(.:format)                    home#create
      new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)                home#new
     edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format)           home#edit
          home GET    /home/:id(.:format)                home#show
               PUT    /home/:id(.:format)                home#update
               DELETE /home/:id(.:format)                home#destroy
    find_index GET    /find(.:format)                    find#index
               POST   /find(.:format)                    find#create
      new_find GET    /find/new(.:format)                find#new
     edit_find GET    /find/:id/edit(.:format)           find#edit
          find GET    /find/:id(.:format)                find#show
               PUT    /find/:id(.:format)                find#update
               DELETE /find/:id(.:format)                find#destroy
 promote_index GET    /promote(.:format)                 promote#index
               POST   /promote(.:format)                 promote#create
   new_promote GET    /promote/new(.:format)             promote#new
  edit_promote GET    /promote/:id/edit(.:format)        promote#edit
       promote GET    /promote/:id(.:format)             promote#show
               PUT    /promote/:id(.:format)             promote#update
               DELETE /promote/:id(.:format)             promote#destroy
      settings GET    /settings(.:format)                settings#index
               POST   /settings(.:format)                settings#create
   new_setting GET    /settings/new(.:format)            settings#new
  edit_setting GET    /settings/:id/edit(.:format)       settings#edit
       setting GET    /settings/:id(.:format)            settings#show
               PUT    /settings/:id(.:format)            settings#update
               DELETE /settings/:id(.:format)            settings#destroy
          root        /                                  home#index
                      /auth/:provider/callback(.:format) sessions#create
  auth_failure        /auth/failure(.:format)            :controller#:action
        logout        /logout(.:format)                  sessions#destroy
          find        /find(.:format)                    find#index
       promote        /promote(.:format)                 promote#index
      settings        /settings(.:format)                settings#index
```

EDIT: The issue seems to be in Google Chrome.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, have you tried with different browsers?

Comment: Yes. Basically I am on `GET promote_index`, which contains form for `POST promote_index` which than redirects me back to `GET promote_index`. But when I hit F5 after I've been redirected, it wants to resubmit form again.

Comment: I don't think you need the key flash:, `redirect_to promote_index_url, notice: "Promotion has been started"` (Not that this is the error)

Comment: I use flash, because than I can do :flash => { :error => 'Error here' }

Comment: I found this question because I'm having pretty much the same problem. Are you by change using Chrome? I was grasping at straws and tried with Firefox but couldn't reproduce it. Could this be a browser quirk? [update] could be this? https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177855

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and eventually tracked it down to a bug in Chrome (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177855)

The work around I used is just to add some get parameters. Here's how I dealt with both the bug and the frustration. The result may not be appropriate for all scenarios. Fortunately my app is internal.

```
def create
  @message = current_user.messages.new(params[:message])
  @message.get_video_id
  if @message.save
    flash[:notice] = "Promotion has been started"
    redirect_to promote_index_url(chrome_bug_workaround: 177855)
  else
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

Another alternative is to create a collection route that is basically an alias for index.

In `routes.rb`:

```
match 'promote/all' => 'promote#index', :as => 'all_promotions'
```

In `promote_controller.rb`:

```
def create
  @message = current_user.messages.new(params[:message])
  @message.get_video_id
  if @message.save
    redirect_to all_promotions_url, flash: {notice: "Promotion has been started"}
  else
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

As an aside, your `find`, `promote`, and `settings` match routes appear to be redundant with the resource routes' index actions.

Comment: Thanks! Hope Chrome gets patched soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your methods to this:

```
def index
    @message = Message.new url: @last_video, message_body: @last_message

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = current_user.messages.new(params[:message])
    @message.get_video_id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        format.html {redirect_to promote_index_url, notice: "Promotion has been started"}
      else
        render 'index'
      end
    end
  end
```